# MyBatis very slow

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm wondering why MyBatis is **slow** in my application.

For a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, the time taken is:

1. 20 secs    - first request
2. 2-3 secs   - subsequent requests

Caching, most likely, is making the subsequent requests faster.

## Configuration

- **3-tier** (WPF UI - Java Backend - Oracle Database)
- **JBoss** Server exposes the Java Backed as a Web-Service for the WPF UI
- **Request time** == time taken between when the WPF UI sends and receives the result
- **Spring Framework** being used

## Approaches tried

1. **Disabled logging**

   I don't know if disabling both the logging subsystem and log4j makes a difference; but, the best I got was 15 secs for the `SELECT COUNT(*)`.
2. **Disabled Caching and Lazy loading**

   This too probably made a 5 sec difference at most.

### Do the following help?

1. Using explicit **result mapping**, by turning off auto-mapping. (See Result Maps [here](http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html)).
2. Using **Pooling**. (See environments [here](http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html)).
3. Do **transactions** help speed up SQL statements with **sub-queries**?

The above techniques are listed here:

1. [MyBatis forums](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/myBatis-is-slow-td2236249.html)
2. [JBoss Best Practices](http://www.jboss.com/pdf/JB_JEAP4_3_PerformanceTuning_wp.pdf) (Page 9)

#### Another example

For a nested SQL statement with 2 joins and 1 sub-query, the time taken is:

1. 60-90 secs - first request
2. 2-3 secs   - subsequent requests

Comment: Do you see similar behavior running the same queries directly on the database?

Comment: @AngerClown The response is very fast when I query directly. It's about 0.3s for the `SELECT COUNT(*)` and 1.5s for the query with 2 joins and a sub-query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the problems solved! *MyBatis* now takes the same time to query as running directly against the database.

It was the **N+1 selects problem** (nicely described [here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps)).

## Solution

**Nested Results** (as opposed to **Nested Select**), which is also described on the same page mentioned above.

The difference it made to my SQL query with 4 joins was enormous:

- **Before:** 38 s
- **After:** 3 s

I tracked the problem down by isolating it to a **JUnit** test-case around *MyBatis-Spring* (removing the *JBoss* part).